# Conditionals in ML

Tags: if-statement, ml

I am beginning to learn ML and we went over this piece of code in lecture:

```
val x = 1;
if hd [1, 2, 3] = x then x = x + 1 else x = x - 1;
```

Does this statement return false because the head of [1, 2, 3] is equal to 1, so it goes into the then part and compares 1 to 1 + 1?

Comment: Yes. There's not much more to add. Except perhaps that it's not a statement but an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct. It will evaluate to `x = x + 1` which is `1 = 1 + 1` which is `false`.

Note that it will evaluate to `false` no matter which branch is taken, because `x` is never equal to `x + 1` or `x - 1`.